# Novice to Ninja growl message - .on function not working for elements added with setTimeout

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have implemented the novice-to-ninja growl notifications. But the final notification is not going. I have even checked the original sitepoint code and there also the final message stays.

Nothing happens when I click the close button for the second bubble - added with setTimeout i.e.

```
<p>Stay awhile!</p><p>Stay FOREVER!</p>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

The javascript code is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
addNotice('<p>Welcome to StarTrackr!</p>');

setTimeout(function() {
    addNotice('<p>Stay awhile!</p><p>Stay FOREVER!</p>');
}, 1000);

$('#growl')
.find('.close')
.on('click', function() {
    $(this)
        .closest('.notice')
        .animate({
            border: 'none',
            height: 0,
            marginBottom: 0,
            marginTop: '-6px',
            opacity: 0,
            paddingBottom: 0,
            paddingTop: 0,
            queue: false
        }, 1000, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
});
});

function addNotice(notice) {
$('<div class="notice"></div>')
    .append('<div class="skin"></div>')
    .append('<a href="#" class="close">close</a>')
    .append($('<div class="content"></div>').html(notice))
    .hide()
    .appendTo('#growl')
    .fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
$('#growl')
    .on('click', '.close', function() {
```

The `.close` element is created dynamically and `.find()` won't find it at that point because it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: That was spot on & resolved - many thanks!  Though I didn't understand how come one bubble was getting closed and infact I tried - any bubble added without setimeout did get closed. It was only the second one that was not getting closed.